# Express could not store cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to store a login-session into a cookie when a user login in via username/passport, so the server knows the user is logged in. But the cookie will never be set.

Here is the relevant code:

**index.js:**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require("dotenv").config();
}

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "16mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "16mb" }));

const session = require("express-session");
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "thisIsMySecretMessageHowWillYouGuessIt",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: 'none',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true
    },
  })
);

const passport = require("passport");
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());

const cors = require("cors");

const whitelist = env.process.CLIENT_URL;
app.use(cors({ origin: whitelist, credentials: true }));
```

**auth.js:**

```
const cookieKey = "sid";
const md5 = require("md5");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);
const cookieOption = { maxAge: 3600 * 1000, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true};

login = async (req, res) => {
    const sessionKey = md5(
      getSecretMessage() + new Date().getTime() + user.username
    );

    client.hmset("sessions", sessionKey, JSON.stringify(user), function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    // this sets a cookie
    res.cookie(cookieKey, sessionKey, cookieOption);   // expire after 60 mins

    res.send({ username: user.username, result: "success" });
};

isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (
    (req.cookies === undefined || req.cookies[cookieKey] === undefined) &&
    !req.isAuthenticated()
  ) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
    return;
  }
};
```

The req.cookies['sid'] will always be undefined, so the server would return 401 status.

For the react client, the 'credentials' has been set to 'include'.

**Things I tried:**

1. Flipping around the 'secure' values in the cookie option in both index.js and auth.js
2. Used 'express-samesite-default' package

One point to notice is that the functionality was working half-year ago, there might be some dependencies update so it changed the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You could use local storage.
Local storage saves on the clients device and is accessible using `localStorage.getItem('key')` and you can add items by using the `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`.

Comment: that would work I guess. But how could the server tell if a request is authorized